# search for artist (string) in row in section of tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am new to Swift!  I can properly display all of the artists in the tableview.  But, I can not figure out how to find a string (artist name) in the list of sectioned artists that were returned from a query.  My code can find any artist in the first section but not in any others.  It appears that my rowNum is not being reset to 0 before I start searching the next section (although I tried).  Example: section 0 (the letter A) currently has 12 artists (0 - 11).  If I try to find the 3rd artist (The Beatles) in section 1 (the letter B), I get the proper section number of 1, but the row number of 14 (and rowNum should be 2 for The Beatles).

```
var qryArtists = MPMediaQuery.artistsQuery()
var rowNumInSectionWhereArtistWasFound = 0
var sectionNumOfSectionWhereArtistWasFound = 0

func findIndexAndSectionOfArtistInQuery(artist: String) {
    var sectionNum = 0
    var rowNum = 0
    var found = false
    // Search each section
    while (sectionNum < qryArtists.itemSections?.count) && (found == false) {
    // Search each row in the current section
        while (rowNum < qryArtists.collectionSections![sectionNum].range.length) && (found == false) {
            if qryArtists.collections![rowNum].items[0].artist == artist {
                rowNumInSectionWhereArtistWasFound = rowNum
                sectionNumOfSectionWhereArtistWasFound = sectionNum
                found = true
            }
            rowNum = rowNum + 1
        }
        sectionNum = sectionNum + 1
        rowNum = 0  // Reset the rowNum each time you start searching a new section
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for helping1!

Comment: qryArtists.collectionSections![sectionNum].range.length) is not returning correct value , it should return total no of artist per section rit ! Just change it to get the total no of **artist per section** will fix your issue

Comment: Thank you very much but how?  I can't figure out what to change it to.

Comment: I checked.  qryArtists.collectionSections![sectionNum].range.length gives me 12 artists in section 0 followed by 23 artists in section 1.  These values are correct.  I need rowNum = 2.  14 is what is being determined (12 + 2 = 14).  rowNum should count up to 12 for section 0 and then get rest to 0 so that it can then count up to 2 for section 1.

Comment: I found it .  Essentially, the " pointer" had to be advanced because you aren't actually looking into each section from scratch.  The following fixed it:         

    let currLoc = qryArtists.collectionSections![sectionNum].range.location;
    let rowItem = qryArtists.collections![rowNum + currLoc];
                
     if rowItem.items[0].artist == artist { }

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have a function that searches your tableview and returns an `NSIndexPath` (the object that encapsulates both row and section), this will search through your cells, asking each cell (which I assume holds a reference to its artist property) if they have a matching name:

```
func findIndexAndSectionOfArtistInQuery(artist: String) -> NSIndexPath {
    for indexSection in 0...tableView.numberOfSections {
        let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexSection)
        for indexRow in 0...numberOfRows {
            let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexRow, inSection: indexSection)
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CustomCell
            if(cell!.artist.name == artist) {
                return indexPath
            }
        }
    }
    return nil        
}
```

This function will return `nil` if an artist cannot be found.

I advise you to reconsider your approach. You should be querying your model, not your tableview for data. In addition, you should consider creating a separate class for searching your model in the most efficient way.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.  I am new to iOS and Swift!  I'm confused.  I guess I thought my code was essentially dealing with the result of the query (model) and not my tableview.  I'm interesting in trying your approach, but your code refers to tableView.  Is your code the right way go?

Comment: I'm not going to design your model for you, but in general iOS uses the MVC pattern. The Model portion is usually responsible for holding your app's relevant data, as well as performing CRUD operations. The Controller portion of MVC, is responsible for responding to events propagated in the View element of MVC. In your case, you should be populating your tableview via your model. Additionally, your model could also be responsible for basic operations (search, CRUD ops).

Comment: I tried your code but it produces an error.  Can't assign nil where an NSIndexPath is expected.  But I appreciate you time and effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the following code in place of the actual "test" fixed it.

```
let currLoc = qryArtists.collectionSections![sectionNum].range.location
let rowItem = qryArtists.collections![rowNum + currLoc]
if rowItem.items[0].artist == artist {
}
```